# How to choose median filter width?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, median-filter

In my signal processing pipeline, I normally expect data sampled at 100Hz, on which I then apply a median filter of width 10.

My question is: How should I change the width for data sampled at different rates?

For example, say an incoming data is sampled at 50Hz. Should I then use a median filter of width 5 to be consistent? In other words, should I choose the median filter based on the physical time length (0.1 seconds in our case) instead of number of ticks?

Comment: That all depends on the purpose of your median filtering  – what do you do it for?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I apply it to smooth the signal to remove potential outliers/noise. In particular, this is wearable sensor data (like Fitbit).

Comment: I think the answer is yes.